# Synaptic stopped responding

Tags: synaptic

When troubleshooting no-response for Synaptic,in the "Edit Launcher" window command-line says "/usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec" but file manager shows "X11" where pkexec should be.
Trying to open this X11 directory returns endless X11 directory icons, but no-way to open this directory...
Is this malware, a bug,or something-else?
Have already removed and reinstalled synaptic with same results.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/X11` is a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) pointing to `/usr/bin/`. So if you open `/usr/bin/X11` you actually open `/usr/bin/`, and that still contains the symlink `X11` pointing to `/usr/bin/` ...

This symlink is used as the folder `/usr/bin/X11` isn't really used any more by Ubuntu and all the files it used to contain are really in `/usr/bin/` now. Thanks to the symlink they are still found in their old place if a program or user is expecting them there.

The file `/usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec` is part of the package `synaptic` so it should be there if Synaptic is installed. As there are a lot of files in `/usr/bin/` it may take some time for the file manager to show them all.

On the command line you can use

```
ls -l /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
```

to check if the file `/usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec` is there. The output should be something like

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43 Jan 30  2012 /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
```